# guys when i edit a smali file i change the text to be shown on the pop up when launching app the text does not show but the pop up still apear

Tags: smali

guys when i edit a smali file i change the text to be shown on the pop up when launching app the text does not show but the pop up still apear

## virtual methods

.method public onClick(Landroid/view/View;)V
.locals 4

```
iget-object v0, p0, LbotX/mod/p/ۦۖۤ;->ۨۚۖۗ:Landroid/app/AlertDialog;

invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/app/AlertDialog;->dismiss()V

iget-object v0, p0, LbotX/mod/p/ۦۖۤ;->ۢۘۤۗ:Landroid/content/Context;

new-instance v1, Landroid/content/Intent;

const-string v2, "android.intent.action.VIEW"

const-string v3, "http://MODDROID.CO"

invoke-static {v3}, Landroid/net/Uri;->parse(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/net/Uri;

move-result-object v3

invoke-direct {v1, v2, v3}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/net/Uri;)V

invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/content/Context;->startActivity(Landroid/content/Intent;)V

return-void
```

.end method

Answer (score 0):

The code you have included into your question does not look like a "popup" instead the default web browser is opened using the URL `http://MODDROID.CO`.

If this is the "popup" you are talking about you can simply comment out the
line

```
invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/content/Context;->startActivity(Landroid/content/Intent;)V
```

Commenting out this line here does not have any side effect on the app.